# Laravel File Storage: How to store (decoded) base64 image?

Tags: php, laravel, base64, laravel-filesystem, laravel-storage

How to store base64 image using the [Laravel's filesytem (File Storage)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem) methods?

For example, I can decode base64 image like this:

```
base64_decode($encoded_image);
```

but all of the Laravel's methods for storing files can accept either a `Illuminate\Http\File` or `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` instance.

So I guess I'd have to convert base64 image (or decoded base64 image) to `Illuminate\Http\File` or `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`, but how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `put` to store the encoded contents:

```
Storage::put('file.jpg', $encoded_image);
```

All it's doing is wrapping `file_put_contents`.

Then to read it back out:

```
$data = base64_decode(Storage::get('file.jpg'));
```

Which, you guess it, is wrapping `file_get_contents`.

Comment: can we use base64 encoding for pdf file as well?

Answer (score 16):

You can upload your base64 Image using laravel File Storage like this

```
    $base64_image = $request->input('base64_image'); // your base64 encoded     
    @list($type, $file_data) = explode(';', $base64_image);
    @list(, $file_data) = explode(',', $file_data); 
    $imageName = str_random(10).'.'.'png';   
    Storage::disk('local')->put($imageName, base64_decode($file_data));
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: You can strip away `disk('local')` because the default value is `'local'`.
`Storage::put($imageName, base64_decode($file_data));`

Answer (score 1):

**2023** Working Solution:

Just use that amazing Laravel Package and do your job in just three lines:

**Reference:** https://github.com/oldravian/multi-source-file-uploader

```
$file_uploader_factory = new 
\OldRavian\FileUploader\Factories\FileUploaderFactory();
$file_uploader = $file_uploader_factory->build("base64");

//first parameter should be a string (base64 encoded string)
//second parameter is optional, if you leave that parameter then default settings will be used
$data = $file_uploader->upload($encoded_image, $uploadSettings);
```

The above function will return an associative array like:

```
[
    'filename' => 'uploaded file name',
    'path' => 'path to file location relative to the disk storage',
    'url' => 'public url to access the file in browser'
]
```

**$uploadSettings** is an associative array with the following possible keys:

- directory: the root directory containing your uploaded files
- disk: the storage disk for file upload. Check Laravel official documentation for
  more details, e.g: public, s3
- maxFileSize (in bytes): the maximum size of an uploaded file
- allowedExtensions: array of acceptable file extensions, e.g: ['jpg', 'png', 'pdf']

**In addition to base64, this package also supports file uploading by file object and URL.**