# how to get laravel uploaded file path when converted from base 64

Tags: laravel, file-upload, base64, storage

I am trying to path of the uploaded file. The file is sent in base64 when laravel receives it laravel converts it to a file and uploads it to storage folder.

```
 preg_match("/data:image\/(.*?);/",$image,$image_extension); // extract the image extension
        $image = preg_replace('/data:image\/(.*?);base64,/','',$image); // remove the type part
        $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
        $imageName = 'passports/image_' . time() . '.' . $image_extension[1]; //generating unique file name;
        
return  Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName,base64_decode($image));
```

What I get is 1 after the file has uploaded perfectly well.

Comment: There is an similar existing answer. You might want to check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/51297138/946238